# List of Base64 images embedded in Thymeleaf will not display

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I ended up making a List of images received from my database where they are stored as LongBlob. After receiving them, I then create a new list of base64 and encode those values into the Base64 list. The issue is that when I go to insert this into Thymeleaf it doesn't display any images.

User.java

```
@Entity
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  private String firstName;

  private String lastName;

  private String username;

  private String email;

  private String phoneNumber;


  @OneToOne
  private Demographic demographic;

  @OneToOne
  private Resume resume;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JsonIgnore
  private List<Skills> userSkills;

  public User() {
  }
  ... getters/setters
}
```

Skills.java

```
@Entity
public class Skills {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  private String techName;
  private byte[] logo;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user   ;

  public Skills() {
  }
  ... getters/setters
}
```

HomeController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  @Autowired
  private SkillsService skillsService;


  @RequestMapping("/home")
  public String showHome() {
      return "index";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/portfolio")
  public String showPortfolio() {
      return "portfolio";
  }

  GetMapping(value = "/technology")
public String technologyList(Model theModel) throws IOException {
    User user = userService.findByUsername("wmangram");
    List<Skills> userSkillsList = skillsService.findSkillList("wmangram");

    List<byte[]> logo = skillsService.findLogos();
    List<String> base64List = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < logo.size(); i++) {
        byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64(logo.get(i));
        String base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64, "UTF-8");
        base64List.add(base64Encoded);
    }
    theModel.addAttribute("userSkills", userSkillsList);
    theModel.addAttribute("userImages", base64List);

    /*for (int j = 0; j < base64List.size(); j++) {
        theModel.addAttribute("userImage", base64List.get(j));
        System.out.println("\\\nThis is the base64 called for: " + base64List.get(j));
    }*/
    /*for (int j = 0; j < logo.size(); j++) {
        theModel.addAttribute("logo", logo.get(j));
        System.out.println("\\\nThis is the logo called for: " + logo.get(j));
    }
    theModel.addAttribute("logo", logo);
    */



    return "technology";
}
```

skills.html

```
<tbody>                                      
  <tr th:if="${userSkills.empty}">                                           
     <td colspan="2"> No Skills Available </td>                                      
  </tr>                                      
  <tr th:each="skills : ${userSkills}">
    <td><span th:text="${skills.techName}"></span></td>
    <td>
        <img th:src="@{'data:image/png;base64,${userImages}}"/>
    </td>
  </tr>                              
</tbody>
```

Comment: Hi Matt, I'm sorry but I copied over some old code and text that I had previously and updated them accordingly. 


I do have them encoded and stored in List<String> and I'm calling them in the Thymeleaf page with <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${userImages}" />

Comment: And what actually get rendered to the client? What seems to be the issue specifically?

Comment: Just a small square image you see when an image can't be displayed. It's as if Thymeleaf isn't picking up the individual Base64 encoding

Comment: Sorry, I mean in text. What does it actually evaluate to? What comes back from the server for text?

Comment: <img src="&#39;data:image/png;base64,${userImages}"/> is what I get in the source code, as far as the Sysout comment I have, I'm adding it into the OP

Comment: Never mind I was going to input the text but it's obnoxiously long, however, it's returning the Base64 encoded String for each in the list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should probably look something like this:

```
<img th:src="|data:image/png;base64,${userImages[0]}|"/>
```

Based on your comments, you should have all the tools you need to debug this.  You said this is what when you view the source:

```
<img src="&#39;data:image/png;base64,${userImages}"/>
```

Therefore you know that the Thymeleaf variable wasn't being evaluated.  Also, `userImages` is an array, so you need to index into it.  You'll have to figure out the correct index though, since you aren't looping over the array I'm not sure how to write that part of the code.

Comment: You're awesome Metroids! Applied that to the thymeleaf page and was able to acquire one of the images.

The goal I have is to get it to iterate the list and display them but if I have to go in and manually insert each one then that's not too big of a deal.

Comment: Wanted to add, I figured out iterating the list and displaying the images. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to display it in the same row as the appropriate skill in the userSkills list without it display all images in each. Instead I made two separate rows and use th:each="" in the <td> which gave me a neat looking horizontal view of the skills. I apprieciate everyones help!